# WordPress Multisite Geolocation Subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, network-programming

There are other questions on this, but none seem to fit my user case.

I have two instances of a website, both are in English but using WordPress Multisite there is European version and an American version of the site.

This was set up by a predecessor, but I am trying to find an alternative to WordPress Multisite because most of the posts (~75%) belong on both Europe and America versions, and I don't want the content creators to have to worry about logging in to two dashboards and posting the same post twice.

This really doesn't have to be a WordPress specific question, I am just wondering how typical networking is done for a job like this where:

1). Theme is to remain the same

2). Posts are mostly the same and it would be nice if there was *just one dashboard* and plugin/function on a post to say publish for Europe, America, or both.

3). Users would have to opt-in to join the Europe site if they were already on the America site, but they wouldn't have to re-register, kind of like how users can join across the StackOverflow network.

I think I know how to do this if I were to write my own little CMS using another PHP or Node framework, it would just be a property of the various posts as to what geo they were published for and similarly each user would say what geo they were registered for, and then when querying the database from a given subdomain I would query for posts by the geo attached to that subdomain, as a kind of constant in the query.

Given I have WordPress install, what is the easiest way to accomplish such goals in WordPress or do I need my own solution? Also how do sites like StackOverflow manage users across various networks?

Furthermore if I wanted to accomplish this in a more do-it-yourself framework like Laravel, what are some of the general principles in order to accomplish this and not manage two sites but leverage something like Cloudlfare to point to subdomains based on gelocation and serve the same site but with different database queries?

Answer (score 0):

I don't even understand why you would need a multisite setup for this. All you are trying to do is organise content, and within Wordpress you do that with [taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

You can use the built in ones like categories or tags or you can create your own. Customise default settings based on geo ip information, or a user setting, or just lets users pick or whatever you want.

You can set it up so users to have to opt in to read posts tagged from across the pond, or just set their default to show local posts but give them a link to view all, or again just put a setting in their admin section.

Build your own CMS if you want, but seems like a real waste of time when this is pretty much exactly what Wordpress was designed for and they probably have 50,000+ developer hours headstart on you.

Comment: Thanks, make sense. I didn't think I would need multsite, as I said, that was set up by a predecessor. I wasn't sure how easily taxonomies could be leveraged for showing content based on geographic location.